# Draco NgsiToMongo Processor Issue

Tags: fiware

Good evening

Im stuck with draco. According to the docs, the processor NgsiToMongo should have a "column" option for Attribute Persistence, however no matter what I do , I only have the "row" option. I do see in my setup that NGSIToPostreSQL have such option, but I need to use mongo.
If anybody could assist me with whether its a bug or a way around this issue, i will be forever in your debt.

Answer (score 0):

The column mode was introduced in the FIWARE_7.9.1 release, please check https://github.com/ging/fiware-draco/releases/tag/FIWARE_7.9.1